# With a Javascript IFFE getting a Uncaught TypeError is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, anonymous-types

I was trying to code up some anonymous function  IFFE stuff in JavaScript and I don't understand why I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: dM.getResources is not a function

Fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/MillerDev/5qmnqr6q/

What is causing it?

**reportGroupDataManager**  ( normally this is reportGroupDataManager.js file)

```
var reportGroupDataManager = (function() {
   var self = this;
   // cannot do this below   as dM.getResources is not a function
   //self.getResources = "blah";

  self.getResources = function() {
    return object;
     // return ajaxHelper.get(actions.adminReports.getResourceFileUrl, {});
  };

  console.log('reportGroupDataManager');

  return self;
});
```

**data** (currently placeholder)

```
function data() {
   console.log('in data'); 
}
```

**IFFE**

```
(function(jQ, dM, data) {
    var self = this;

    var initializePage = function () {
       console.log('in init');
    };

    dM.getResources()
        .done(initializePage, function(result) {
            console.log('in fx');
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.CannotDeleteWithChild);
        });

})($, reportGroupDataManager, data);
```

So normally `dM.getResources()`  is going to fetch data from the `reportGroupDataManager` in which  `result` is a object

but with this code I'm not sure why the error

same Fiddle as above  --> https://jsfiddle.net/MillerDev/5qmnqr6q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reportGroupDataManager` is a constructor, not an object. But you're expecting an object created by `reportGroupDataManager`. Therefore the IIFE should be this:

```
(function(){
   // ...
})($, new reportGroupDataManager(), data);
```

Comment: BTW, constructors don't need to return anything. Not even `this` (in your case `self`)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: reportGroupDataManager is not a constructor

Comment: @MillRunner: You must have a typo or something because it works: https://jsfiddle.net/slebetman/yecgm1bp/

Comment: @MillRunner: It even works with your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/slebetman/5qmnqr6q/1/

Comment: object is not defined

Comment: So if I return  object  then object is not defined , then if i `self.getResources = function() {
   return "blah"; 
  };`   then    i'm back to error  `dM.getResources(...).done is not a function`

Comment: @MillRunner: Then define `object`. Since object is assumed to have a `.done()` method it's obvious you intend `object` to be a promise (or something promise-like like jQuery deferreds)

Comment: Even if I do this  :   `var t = "blah";
    return t;`   i still have an error  `dM.getResources is not a function`  Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/MillerDev/x3t0Lhdg/2/

Comment: @MillRunner: Well, I answered that: you need to create the object from the constructor using `new`.

Comment: @MillRunner: A working version of your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/slebetman/x3t0Lhdg/4/

Comment: @MillRunner: I strongly suggest you read up on what objects and constructors are in javascript

Answer (score 0):

dM is not a constructor function therfore you can not use "this" as a refrance to dM

you need to 'new' the function like this

```js
function ReportGroupDataManager(){
this.getResources = function(){
  return object
}
}

let reportGroupDataManager = new ReportGroupDataManager()

(function(jQ, dM, data) {
    var self = this;

    var initializePage = function () {
       console.log('in init');
    };

    dM.getResources()
        .done(initializePage, function(result) {
            console.log('in fx');
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.CannotDeleteWithChild);
        });

})($, reportGroupDataManager, data);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function